# How can I duplicate value into Gsheets with apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I like to modify this script to duplicate a single record as many times as I need into gsheets.

As of now my script below just posts a single record as intended.

Now I like to add a variable(quantity) and have the record posted(append) onto the sheet as many times as the quantity variable says.

```
     function sendProductIDtoQRCodeSheet(fieldData){
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1fUNWqzHosafsdafasdfas--B4').getSheetByName('LISTS');
     var lRow = sheet.getLastRow();
     var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");

     var value1 = fieldData.productId;
     var value2 = fieldData.productName;
     var joinedValues = value1 + " | " + value2;

     sheet.appendRow([ 
          fieldData.productId, joinedValues
              ]);

      }
```

Comment: Can you share the sheet to try it and clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to achieve what you want, you can use a `for` loop and a take a look at these methods since they can be of help:

- [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) - for getting the range with the **given** numbers of rows and columns;
- [`setValues(values)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) - for setting the **values** on the specified range for which they **must** match the dimensions of it;

You might also want to search similar questions here on Stack which can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use a loop?

Check the [documentation for the sheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). There's a method called insertRows(rowIndex, numRows) that could be what you're looking for. It inserts a number of blank rows equal to numRows at the index. You can just populate them after you make them.

Comment: Indeed I could use a for loop, but I'm not sure how to structure it!

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood the question then. Some reading that might be helpful is this: https://www.bazroberts.com/2017/04/13/apps-script-basics-loops/

Comment: You essentially want to set a variable called quantity as you mentioned to be equal to the number of repetitions you want, and then use that in your for loop, like such: [for (r=1; r<=quantity; r++){ //add rows here}}]. Here r is your iterator, but you can also use it to specify which row you want to add data to.

Comment: So I got   for (i=1; i<=quantity; i++) {
sheet.getRange(i, 1).setValue([joinedValues]); and it works to post it to the sheet. But I have a problem appending  multiple variables to the next available row. I'm not sure of the syntax.

Comment: Never mind sheet.getRange(i, 1).setValue([value1,joinedValues]); Thank you for getting me in the right path.

Comment: I thought I had it but still can't get the two values in to both columns.
 sheet.getRange(i +lastRow, 1).setValue([value1,value2]);
I have also used setValues, but it gives me an error
>>The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues<<

Comment: So I think your issue is that you're trying to put multiple values into your range, when you only have a single cell to work with. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column says that passing only two arguments returns a range with a single cell. the setValues() function (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) must match the size of the range. You'll want to use getRange(row, column, numRows), or getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) as appropriate for your needs.